# How to remove time from datetime column in dataset?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have to export data to excel sheet in asp.net c# application. Now I have wriiten below lines of code

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = ds.Tables[0];
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            row["ExpiryDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(row["ExpiryDate"]).ToShortDateString();
        }
        DataSet dsn = new DataSet();
        DataTable dtcopy = dt.Clone();
        dsn.Tables.Add(dtcopy);
WebUtility.GenrateExcel(ds, "ExpiredDocuments");
```

I want to first remove time from data set's Expiry date column and then pass 
it to the generate Excel function so that time will not appear in Expiry date column in excel... Please help the above code is not working...

Comment: Let me ask. Is _ExpiryDate_ a DateTime column or a string one?

Comment: What is the format of `ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ExpiryDate"]`? Any error code?

Comment: it is datetime column

Comment: In this case whatever you do it'll display the time since `DateTime` is the datatype of your `ExpiryDate` column. Better add a string column and convert the `ExpiryDate ` value to date only and assign it there.

Comment: Your line inside the for loop doesn't do anything. Sure you call convert on a column and then ask to get a string in the ShortDate format but you don't reassign this value to anything. When you call your GenerateExcel method the ExpiryDate is still a DateTime. And no you can't assign the string back to the column because it is still a datetime column. This conversion should be executed by the GenerateExcel method (perhaps passing a flag to instruct the removal of time values from datetime columns)

Comment: try `ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ExpiryDate"]=Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ExpiryDate"]).ToShortDateString();` to update the value of the dataset. other wise you will need to use [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750603/exporting-to-excel-loses-the-date-format)

Comment: can we pass old dataset values in new dataset after removing time... if yes

Comment: You can use [linq to datatable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552415%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this purpose. [More example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399401%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: can u please provide code segment

Comment: If you want to display the value in *Excel* in a certain way, post the code that generates *the Excel file*. At most, you need to change the sheet column's format. You can also get the date part of a DateTime with DateTime.Date, eg `row["ExpiryDate"]=((DateTime)row["ExpiryDate"]).Date;`

Answer (score -1):

I guess, you need look through this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

You should use smth like

```
Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ExpiryDate"]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Or whatever you need.

Comment: This doesn't CHANGE (hint) anything

Comment: This *could* change the data and break it beyond recognition - in any locale that doesn't use the US  date format

Answer (score -1):

These are the steps you need to do in order to accomplish what you are asking:

1. Create a new column of type string
2. Set the new column's value to `ShortDateString` of the corresponding "ExpiryDate" column
3. Remove the "ExpiryDate" column
4. Move the new string column to the position of the old "ExpiryDate" column
5. Rename the new column to "ExpiryDate"

Like so:

```
        dt.Columns.Add("ExpiryDateString", typeof(String));
        foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            row["ExpiryDateString"] = ((DateTime)row["ExpiryDate"]).ToShortDateString();
        }
        int columnNumber = dt.Columns["ExpiryDate"].Ordinal;
        dt.Columns.Remove("ExpiryDate");
        dt.Columns["ExpiryDateString"].SetOrdinal(columnNumber);
        dt.Columns["ExpiryDateString"].ColumnName = "ExpiryDate";
```