# ASP.NET - datatable to excel - change date format

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, date

I am generating xls file from ASP DataTable:

```
var excelGrid = new DataGrid { DataSource = dataTable };
excelGrid.DataBind();
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
Response.Charset = Encoding.UTF8.EncodingName;

var fileName = "export_" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ".xls";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
Response.BinaryWrite(Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());

var swriter = new StringWriter();
var hwriter = new HtmlTextWriter(swriter);

excelGrid.RenderControl(hwriter);

Response.Write(swriter.ToString());
Response.End();
```

I write date using this formatting

```
row[dataTable.Columns[i++]] = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

The problem is that Excel displays it as dd.mm.yyyy.
Can I force Excel to display this date in my format? How can I do this?

Comment: I don't know the type of your objects but I somehow doubt that a control of type `DataGrid` when _rendered_ to `TextWriter` will produce an output of type `application/vnd.xls`. I'm tempted to think that you have an HTML table served with the wrong MIME type (but Excel just opens it after a warning about extension that does not match content).

Comment: You aren't generating an Excel file. You're generating an HTML file, serving it up with an Excel MIME type and extension. Why not generate an actual Excel file with a library, where you'll have full control over its content?

Comment: I think you can't force Excel to display date  as you want in that way. But with use of excel library or excel interop that may be possible.

Comment: @BhubanShrestha Please do not suggest Excel interop as a possible solution for ASP.NET. That is a [terrible idea](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office).

Comment: Please consider using EpPlus https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/. I recommend. It's very easy and have all this problems fugured out.

Comment: @mason yeah using excel interop for asp.net would be bad idea. I didn't considered that while commenting. Thanks for correcting me. OP should consider choosing some decent Excel Library.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti,  mason: Using a DataGrid to produce "Excel" is a known hack, but it's just a hack. I join PedroSouki in recommending EPPlus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your system settings are overruling the formatting when opening in Excel. As it is nothing more than html content you're sending out there to the client. If you keep using that piece of code, try adding an apostrophe to the line where you write the date:

```
row[dataTable.Columns[i++]] = "'" + date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

This way, excel won't see this as a Date field and thus not following the system setting's short date notation. If this is fine by you... it will load/show as a text field.

If you still want go along with your coding, but dislike the apostrophe when viewing the resulting file in excel, then read up [this first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750603/exporting-to-excel-loses-the-date-format) and then [that](http://www.niallodoherty.com/post.cfm/basic-html-to-excel-formatting) for extended info on mso-number-format.

Answer (score 0):

When adding the DataTable columns, set the colum type as string, like

```
dataTable.Columns.Add("Date1", typeof(string));
```

Then when adding the rows set a DateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") to the column slot.

```
dataTable.Rows.Add(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

This makes your Excel file to understand it later as a string and to not try and format it by itself as a date.

Comment: I gave this answer assuming you are generating an actual Excel file. In case you don't, try OfficeOpenXml

Comment: Why are you assuming an actual Excel file is generated, when the question itself shows exactly how it's generated?

Comment: Office Open XML SDK is terrible with Excel. A horrible API you wouldn't find your arms and legs in. I recommend using EPPlus, which wraps the SDK with a reasonable set of API.

Comment: I can make a xlsx file that works both with MS Office as with LibreOffice from a DataSet with 30 lines of code with it. It is a lot better than the previous library I was using.